# Witcher 3 New Game+ Level Cap

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have a question about the relatively new `DLC` for Witcher 3 `New Game+`:
I read, that there is no level cap, so you can play the complete Game with the story and after that you can farm till Level x, or how is it to understand?

I have played about 200 hours now and actually don't want to continue in order to find out the answer for the question above by myself.

Comment: Hi h0ch5tr4355: do you mean the official new game plus dlc, or a new mod also called new game+?

Comment: I mean the official New game plus `DLC`. Sorry for confusing by writing `mod`. I edited it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no level cap in The Witcher 3, but killing monsters is worth very little XP -  primary experience income is on-level quests.

For this reason, you can level as high as you want through NG+, but you will have a hard time "farming XP" afterwards.

Comment: OK, so basically the game keeps the same and it doesn't turn into a farming fest. That's what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is a level cap as of patch 1.12. My new game+ capped me at level 70.